# Multiple rows convert in to column and column should be count of rows in sql DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables in below format:

**Table 1:**

```
R.no       name      type
--------------------------
1.          Apple    1
2.          Apple    2
3           Apple.   3
4.          Apple.   1
5           apple.   2
```

**Table 2:**

```
R.no     type.     S. Name
-------------------------------
1.         1.       Fresh
2.         2.       Bbbb
3.         3.       Cccc
```

My required output is

```
R. No.  Name.    Fresh.    Bbbb.     Cccc
-------------------------------------------
1.      Apple.   2.        2.        1
```

can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your output.

Comment: I believe it suppose to be simple count of types and pivot the result

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
with cte as 
(
  select A.id, A.value, b.type, b.sname from A inner join B on A.code=B.type
)
 select value,
       sum(case when sname='Fresh' then 1 else 0 end) Fresh,
       sum(case when sname='Bbbb' then 1 else 0 end) Bbbb,
       sum(case when sname='Cccc' then 1 else 0 end) Cccc
from cte
group by value
```

Working fiddle for same is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/76c9f/7).